# postgresql index 100 dimensional and 25 million rows table

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array, indexing, cube

My task is to quickly find the nearest neighbor in 100 dimensional space.
So I create a test table:

```
create extension cube;
create table vectors (id serial, vector cube);
insert into vectors select id, cube(ARRAY[round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000)]) from generate_series(1, 25000000) id;
```

Search request:

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM vectors ORDER BY vector <-> '(705, 501, 321, 345, 591, 58, 229, 420, 341, 628, 84, 476, 700, 71, 815, 616, 45, 686, 886, 102, 378, 172, 263, 538, 665, 553, 475, 845, 540, 963, 893, 209, 479, 357, 914, 70, 415, 142, 490, 756, 770, 574, 232, 470, 645, 47, 86, 690, 733, 972, 792, 112, 144, 55, 650, 810, 608, 125, 655, 148, 88, 548, 357, 567, 905, 271, 637, 320, 413, 128, 76, 183, 702, 308, 653, 347, 355, 739, 37, 88, 711, 829, 200, 856, 884, 850, 665, 493, 975, 320, 641, 63, 869, 998, 630, 774, 269, 268, 94, 682)'::cube LIMIT 10;
```

Without an index, the request to find the nearest neighbor takes about 30 seconds.

Now we will create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX vectors_vector_idx ON vectors USING GIST (vector);
```

Repeat search request:

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM vectors ORDER BY vector <-> '(705, 501, 321, 345, 591, 58, 229, 420, 341, 628, 84, 476, 700, 71, 815, 616, 45, 686, 886, 102, 378, 172, 263, 538, 665, 553, 475, 845, 540, 963, 893, 209, 479, 357, 914, 70, 415, 142, 490, 756, 770, 574, 232, 470, 645, 47, 86, 690, 733, 972, 792, 112, 144, 55, 650, 810, 608, 125, 655, 148, 88, 548, 357, 567, 905, 271, 637, 320, 413, 128, 76, 183, 702, 308, 653, 347, 355, 739, 37, 88, 711, 829, 200, 856, 884, 850, 665, 493, 975, 320, 641, 63, 869, 998, 630, 774, 269, 268, 94, 682)'::cube LIMIT 10;
Limit  (cost=0.55..55.59 rows=10 width=820) (actual time=894342.029..1454440.760 rows=10 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using vectors_vector_idx0 on vectors  (cost=0.55..137606356.86 rows=24999816 width=820) (actual time=894342.027..1454440.754 rows=10 loops=1)
     Order By: (vector <-> '(705, 501, 321, 345, 591, 58, 229, 420, 341, 628, 84, 476, 700, 71, 815, 616, 45, 686, 886, 102, 378, 172, 263, 538, 665, 553, 475, 845, 540, 963, 893, 209, 479, 357, 914, 70, 415, 142, 490, 756, 770, 574, 232, 470, 645, 47, 86, 690, 733, 972, 792, 112, 144, 55, 650, 810, 608, 125, 655, 148, 88, 548, 357, 567, 905, 271, 637, 320, 413, 128, 76, 183, 702, 308, 653, 347, 355, 739, 37, 88, 711, 829, 200, 856, 884, 850, 665, 493, 975, 320, 641, 63, 869, 998, 630, 774, 269, 268, 94, 682)'::cube)
 Planning time: 0.131 ms
 Execution time: 1454440.849 ms
(5 rows)
```

Now the query is executed about 20 minutes.
How can I speed up the search with indexing?

Comment: Can you show the output of the `EXPLAIN`s too?

Comment: I added the output

Comment: The statistics are completely off. Run `vacuum analyze vectors;` then check the plan again

Comment: I've already done the vacuum, but I'll try again

Comment: Retry did not help. I tried with tables having 1 million rows. Vacuum there helped. And with 25 million does not work. Maybe i need some settings for the database to set?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you mean the estimated number of rows in the index scan, I think that is just an artifact because it does not include the 10 row cut-off caused by the `LIMIT`.

Comment: Could you try again with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`? An example of a slow and a fast execution would be marvelous.

Comment: `Limit  (cost=0.55..55.59 rows=10 width=820) (actual time=836353.854..1463364.095 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=24 read=10278404
   ->  Index Scan using vectors_vector_idx0 on vectors  (cost=0.55..137607072.58 rows=25000002 width=820) (actual time=836353.853..1463364.090 rows=10 loops=1)`

Comment: `Buffers: shared hit=24 read=10278404
 Planning time: 0.043 ms
 Execution time: 1463441.931 ms
(7 rows)`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the output inserted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was associated with a small amount of RAM(64 GB) for this task. It looks like the table is fully load into RAM and then there is a search. With indexes the table weighs 100 GB.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS)` is useful to determine things like that, isn't it?

Comment: Laurenz Albe, EXPLAIN (BUFFERS) didn't help me much. I was able to understand this by looking at the schedule for filling the RAM during the execution of the request.

Comment: If the problem is caused by small `shared_buffers`, you should see not only "blocks hit", but also "blocks read" and maybe even "blocks written".